# Moodle Rule types

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I want to apply Moodle rule types: compare and format working with mform elements.
For forename element, input must allow with a format.
For designation element, input must match with any of the array values given. I've given "compare". Both seems not working.

```
<?php     
    require('config.php');
    require_once($CFG->libdir.'/formslib.php');
    
    class active_form extends moodleform {
    
        function definition()   {
                
            $mform = $this->_form;      
            $fileoptions = $this->_customdata['fileoptions'];
    
            $mform->addElement('text', 'forename', get_string('forename', 'form'), 
            array('name'=>'forename[]'));                       
            $mform->setType('forename', PARAM_RAW);
            $mform->addRule('forename', get_string('forename'), 'required', $format='$NAME_00_00#', 
            'client', $force=true);
    
            $mform->addElement('text', 'designation', get_string('designation', 'form'), 
            array('name'=>'designation[]'));                        
            $mform->setType('designation', PARAM_RAW);
            $mform->addRule('designation', get_string('err_designation'), 'compare', 
            array('designation' =>'IT', 'Mechanical', 'EEE', ECE'), 'neq'); 
         
            $this->add_action_buttons();        
        }
    
        function validation($data, $files) {
            $errors = parent::validation($data, $files);
            return $errors;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: It was not working!

Comment: You can't able to use these rules to achieve your needs.
1. The required rule doesn't check the pattern of the field value, Use the **REGEX** rule to check the pattern.
2. The COMPARE rule is used to compare two form fields. Not to check field have any one of the elements listed on the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a specific type of input, you could make a drop down:

```
$mform->addElement('select', 'test','Feedback', array(
    ''=>'',
    'good'=>'Good',
    'soso'=> 'So-So',
    'bad'=>'Bad'
));
$mform->setDefault('test', '');
$mform->setType('test', PARAM_TEXT);
```